# Android Service is Quiting in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, service

I have Android service to run and send email every 9 mins but after some cycles it quits. this  app is also installed  in my Android froyo but it works good for more than 2months now.. I can see the logs in logcat that the service quits but my problem is I cannot understand what does it mean.. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!! any help would be appreciated...

here is my source code:
https://gist.github.com/77a40ac93cd311acb56c

Logcat logs:

https://gist.github.com/dd3ab385d79253fac632

Comment: Hi Yoel

Sorry I forgot to tell you that this logcat was from  my AVD manager because I don't have the phone now in my hands so I simulated the app in AVD manager with the same android version. and that file is needed by another service and there's nothing to do with the service in question.

Comment: I see this errors

11-04 14:34:42.956: I/ActivityManager(61): Force stopping package romel.pi.redphone uid=10034
11-04 14:34:42.966: W/ActivityManager(61): Scheduling restart of crashed service romel.pi.redphone/.BackgroundServices in 5000ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point behind using `AlarmManager` is so that your service only needs to be in memory when it is doing actual work, and can go away in between `AlarmManager` events. You have managed to not do that, and therefore your code will not work reliably.

If you want to "send email every 9 mins", you should:

1. Move the `BroadcastReceiver` to be a public Java class, registered in the manifest via a `<receiver>` element, and remove the `registerReceiver()`/`unregisterReceiver()` stuff.
2. Switch your service to be an `IntentService`, so you get a background thread (which you need for your work, but your current code lacks) and so the service can automatically shut down when there is no more work to be done.
3. Add in the logic for the `WakeLock` that you will need since you are using a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm. You could combine this and the previous steps by switching to [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), if you wish.
4. Deal with the case where the user reboots the device, if you want your alarms to continue after the reboot, such as by scheduling them again via an `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, this is my new method of calling a recurring task every 9 minutes..


I created a startUp receiver to start my alarm manager during boot up - http://goo.gl/n0HYs



this is how I set my AlarmManager to reoccur every 9minutes and broadcast status to my alarm receiver class - http://goo.gl/uz2l1



and this is my alarm receiver class - http://goo.gl/dwyUH



My alarm receiver then call a service to send email and other task every 9minutes - http://goo.gl/aJJdi

Comment: Question:

I am not sure if I am calling the alarmManager correctly.. I am thinking if I can call my startAlarmManager() method without using a service or I can call a normal class during system boot UP with my startUp boot UP receiver..

Comment: The codes above works fine now and I am still observing if it will quit soon ( I hope not ).. ;)